# Select element within nested template in Polymer 1.0

Tags: ajax, templates, nested, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there a way to select an element in a nested template? I have to access ajax within the dom-bind template so I can change the params or url.

```
<template>
    <div class="listing" id="list">
        <template is="dom-bind" id="tmp">
            <iron-ajax id="bin" url="http://api.com/" last-response="{{data}}" handle-as="json" auto></iron-ajax>
            <iron-list  items="[[data]]" as="item">
                <template>
                    <div class="list">
                        <div class="pic">
                            <iron-icon icon="[[item.type]]" class="icon"></iron-icon>
                            <iron-icon class="action"></iron-icon>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cont horizontal layout">
                            <span class="name">[[item.name]]</span>
                            <span class="date">[[item.date]]</span>
                            <span class="time">[[item.time]]</span>
                            <span class="note">[[item.note]]</span>
                        </div>
                        <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
                     </div>
                </template>
            </iron-list>  
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here I have a property named filter. When filter changes it automatically fires `_filterChanged`. I am able to access the #tmp template but I am unable to access the iron-ajax within the #tmp template.

```
Polymer({
    is: "event-log",

    properties: {

        filter: {
            type: String,
            value: "all",
            observer: '_filterChanged'
        }

    },

    _filterChanged: function() {

       var ajax = this.$.tmp.getElementById("bin");
       console.log(ajax); // Returns null

    }

});
```

Comment: Did you try automatic dom binding, i.e. `this.$.bin`? The template usually those not contain any elements. If you have a look at the DOM, the generated elements are inserted below the template object.

Comment: Another way – which is also more Polymer-style, is to use attribute binding on the properties you want to change: `<iron-ajax url="{{myUrlProperty}} params="{{myParamsProperty}}">` and then setting the properties in the change event: `this.set('myUrlProperty', 'http://api.com')` and similarly for the `params`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using <template is="dom-bind"> within an element's template: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind It's only meant to be used outside of an element, e.g. from the context of a top-level HTML page that embeds elements.